# How to get file name from the uploaded file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i want to get the file name and show it in input element using javascript.

i have a button upload clicking that would open the browser to choose file once chosen i should display the chosen file name in input element.

below is my code,

```
const kubeConfig = get(values, `${fieldRoot}.kubeConfig`);

const fileName = useMemo(() => {
    if (kubeConfig) {
        return kubeConfig.name; //cannot read property name of undefined

    }
}, [kubeConfig]) 

<FormField
   label="file"
   fieldId={`${fieldRoot}.kubeConfig`}
>
    {({form}: FieldProps) => (
        <>
            <input 
                type="text"
                value={fileName ?? 'Upload file'}
            /> 
            <input
                type="file"
                style={{display: 'none'}}
                accept=".pem"
                ref={inputRef}
                onChange={async() => {
                   const file = inputRef?.current?.files?.[0];
                   if (file) {
                       try {
                           form.setFieldValue(
                                `${fieldRoot}.kubeConfig`,
                                 file
                           );
                        }
                    }
                }}

            />
            <button onClick={handleUploadClick}> Upload </button>
        )}
    </FormField>
```

i get error cannot read property name of undefined.

kubeconfig data is like below

[image]

I am new to programming learning on the go. could someone help me with this. thanks. how can i access name from kubeConfig data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) have a `files` property that can be interrogated to obtain the file name, MIME type, and size (in bytes).

Each item in the `files` list is a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which is an object (not a string) that has a `.name` property.

For more info, see [Getting information on selected files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#getting_information_on_selected_files) from MDN.

In React, you can get this information from the event argument that is provided to the `onChange` handler. I think that's generally better than using a ref, because it mirrors the pattern you'd use with other kinds of inputs.

---

I think the reason your code is failing is because you're not managing your data well.

I think you want something like this:

```js
let [ filename, setFilename ] = React.useState<string>('')

function onChangeFile( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ): boolean {
    if(event.files && event.files.length) {
        setFilename(event.files[0].name)
    }
    return true
}

<FormField
     label="file"
     fieldId={`${fieldRoot}.kubeConfig`}
>
    {({form}: FieldProps) => (
        <>
            <input 
                type="text"
                value={filename}
            /> 
            <input
                type="file"
                style={{display: 'none'}}
                accept=".pem"
                ref={inputRef}
                onChange={onChangeFile}
            />
            <button onClick={handleUploadClick}> Upload </button>
        </>
    )}
</FormField>
```

A few things to note:

- we don't need two functions for this (one to store and one to retrieve), we only need one change handler
- we use regular React state to hold onto the filename, instead of whatever you're doing with lodash `get`
- this does not use the `form.setFieldValue`; I don't see the implementation of `<FormField>` here, so there's no way for us to know how to use it properly
- I don't see the implementation of `handleUploadClick`, so I'm assuming that all it does is fire a click event on the hidden file input (which is pretty common)

---

Also, you should never define DOM event handlers as `async`. DOM event handlers do not understand Promises. A DOM event handler must return a boolean, *not* a boolean inside a Promise, if you want the page to react properly.

Comment: yes this works. but i am trying to read the file name from kubeConfig. as in edit mode if a file is uploaded already i need to read it from kubeConfig directly. i am getting undefined while accessing name from kubeConfig

Comment: I think there is not enough information in your post for anyone to figure out how to do that. I can say that, whatever mechanism you use to acquire current data from the server about what files have been uploaded previously, you need a better way to integrate that data feed into your React state than what you have. Figuring out the best way will require knowing a lot more about how your UI app is architected, particuarly what you're using for state management and how the component you've partially included fits into the render tree.

Comment: i realised that i have been accesssing the kubeConfig when its undefined as well which was causing the issue. thanks for your  answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this

```js
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
alert("You selected " + fu1.value);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it